# Track when EventBus is not null in Pdf.js

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I use **pdf.js** library in my project and I needed to track the moment when field `PdfViewerApplication.eventBus` becomes not null and is ready for using. Various kinds of solutions such as https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/10718#issuecomment-481175959 not work for me because the source code of **pdf.js** has 2 places where `eventBusDispatchToDOM` property is setted to `false` by default and it is unreal to set it to `true` without changing source code.
Can anyone help me to track when `PdfViewerApplication.eventBus` becomes not null or some way of setting `eventBusDispatchToDOM = true` without changing source code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
waitForEventBus(){
    while (window.PDFViewerApplication == undefined || 
            window.PDFViewerApplication.eventBus == null) {
                console.log("eventBus is null");
                setTimeout(this.waitForEventBus, 100)
                return
            }
    console.log(window.PDFViewerApplication.eventBus);
  }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: i have already solution like yours but i want more reliable solution, because if your have multiple flow of events, you will have a problem in that interval of i.e. 100 ms. If you want to set listener for eventBus on event A, asap when it is initialized, and event A will be fired in that 100ms you will have lost event A.